# TSQL Combine multiple sub queries on same table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, optimization, subquery, query-optimization

I've been trying to improve a SQL query which uses multiple sub queries over the same table but with different conditions and only retrieves the first result from each sub queries.

I will try to simplify the use-case :

I have a table `Products` like this:

| Product_id | reference | field3 | field 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ref1 | val1 | val3 |
| 2 | ref2 | val2 | val4 |

And another table `History`:

| History_id | reference | utilcode | physicalcode | issue | media | datetime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ref1 | 'test' | 'TST' | '0' | '&audio' | 'a_date' |
| 2 | ref2 | 'phone' | 'CALLER' | '1' | '&video' | 'a_date' |
| 3 | ref2 | 'test' | 'CALLER' | '2' | '&test' | 'a_date' |

`History` is a log table and therefore contains a lot of values.

Now I have a query like this

```sql
SELECT 
    p.reference,
    p.field3, p.field4,
    (SELECT TOP 1 a_date 
     FROM history h 
     WHERE h.reference = p.reference 
       AND physicalcode = 'TST' 
       AND issue = 0 
     ORDER BY a_date DESC) AS latest_date_issue_0,
    (SELECT TOP 1 a_date 
     FROM history h 
     WHERE h.reference = p.reference 
       AND physicalcode = 'TST' 
       AND issue = 1 
     ORDER BY a_date DESC) AS latest_date_issue_1
    (SELECT TOP 1 a_date 
     FROM history h 
     WHERE h.reference = p.reference 
       AND utilcode = 'phone' 
     ORDER BY a_date DESC) AS latest_date_phone,
    (SELECT TOP 1 media 
     FROM history h 
     WHERE h.reference = p.reference 
       AND utilcode = 'phone' 
     ORDER BY a_date DESC) AS latest_media,
    -- and so on with many possible combinations
    -- Note that there are more than this few fields on the tables I work on.
WHERE
    p.field3 = 'valX',
    p.field4 = 'valY'
FROM
    products p
```

How could I merge every sub selects ? Or even a few that are alike to improve the performance ?

History being a very big table, selecting over it multiple times drastically slows down the query.

The main problem being that I only need the first value every time.

Thank you for your time and I hope to find a better way to deal with this issue!

I tried to use `ROW_NUMBER()` but I could not find a suitable way to use it.
I also tried to create a tmp table using `WITH` to group every possibility from history but it was worse.

EDIT : Execution plan https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=Sy1AKIsUs

Comment: If you use [paste the plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/instructions/) to add the _actual execution plan_ to your question it might become clear that suitable indexes would address your performance issue. Without DDL it's hard to offer much advice.

Comment: The last two subqueries in your code appear to be identical except for the column selected: `a_date` and `media`. If that's correct, then you could obtain both values in a single operation, e.g. `cross apply`. The _query optimizer_ may already be handling it, as the actual execution plan would show.

Comment: Hello HABO and thank you for your reply.
I did get the execution plan as you suggested : https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=Sy1AKIsUs
I am not familiar with this, I hope it helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @O.Jones I've been able to find a way to improve this query.

What I did to merge a few requests was to use a CTE like so :

From

```sql
SELECT
(SELECT TOP 1 a_date 
     FROM history h 
     WHERE h.reference = p.reference 
       AND physicalcode = 'TST' 
       AND issue = 0 
     ORDER BY a_date DESC) AS latest_date_issue_0,
    (SELECT TOP 1 a_date 
     FROM history h 
     WHERE h.reference = p.reference 
       AND physicalcode = 'TST' 
       AND issue = 1 
     ORDER BY a_date DESC) AS latest_date_issue_1
     (SELECT top 1 a_date 
      FROM history h 
      WHERE h.reference = p.reference 
        AND h.physicalcode = 'TSTKO' 
      ORDER BY h.d_systeme DESC ) AS d_tst_ko,
     (SELECT top 1 a_date 
       FROM history h 
       WHERE h.reference = p.reference 
         AND h.physicalcode = 'CALLERID' 
       ORDER BY h.d_systeme DESC ) AS d_wrong_number
FROM products p
```

To

```sql
WITH physicalcode_cte (reference, physicalcode, issue, a_date)  as
    (
        SELECT reference, physicalcode, issue, max(a_date)
        from historique
        where codephysique in ('TST','TSTKO','CALLERID')
        and a_date > dateadd(month, -4, getdate()) -- filter on date range to reduce number of rows
        group by reference, physicalcode, issue
    )
SELECT
date_issue_0.a_date,
date_issue_1.a_date,
tst_ko.a_date,
wrong_number.a_date
FROM products p
LEFT JOIN physicalcode_cte date_issue_0 on p.reference = date_issue_0.reference 
        AND date_issue_0.codephysique = 'TST' 
        AND date_issue_0.anomalie = 0
LEFT JOIN physicalcode_cte date_issue_1 on p.reference = date_issue_1.reference
        AND date_issue_1.codephysique = 'TST' 
        AND date_issue_1.anomalie = 1
LEFT JOIN physicalcode_cte tst_ko on p.reference = tst_ko.reference
        AND tst_ko.codephysique = 'TST' 
LEFT JOIN physicalcode_cte wrong_number on p.reference = wrong_number.reference AND 
        AND wrong_number.codephysique = 'TST'
```

I've applied this idea for different scenarii and made 2 CTE.
I couldn't merge everything, sometime merging caused cost increase. But after several tests I've been able to go from 7100 total cost to 2100.
It is still a lot but 3 times less anyway. Takes 5 seconds instead of a timeout.
It's a query used for monthly reports so I don't need it to be super fast, I will keep it that way.

Thanks you!

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your correlated subqueries (you call them "subselects") to independent subqueries, then JOIN them. That way each subquery will only need to run once. I'll show you how to do this for your first subquery.

Here's a subquery replacing your first subquery.

```sql
SELECT reference, MAX(a_date) a_date
FROM history
WHERE  physicalcode = 'TST' 
AND issue = 0
GROUP BY reference
```

This gives a virtual table containing the latest date for each reference number from the history table matching the criteria in your question. A multicolumn index on `history (physicalcode, issue, reference, a_date)` makes this fast.

Then you can join it to the main table something like this:

```sql
SELECT 
    p.reference,
    p.field3, p.field4,
    a.a_date a_date_issue_0
FROM products p
LEFT JOIN ( /*the subquery */
           SELECT reference, MAX(a_date) a_date
           FROM history
           WHERE  physicalcode = 'TST' 
           AND issue = 0
           GROUP BY reference
   ) a ON p.reference=a.reference
```

These subqueries can also be defined as VIEWs or Common Table Expressions (CTEs). If you have many of them you'll probably find it easier to read and reason about your query by doing them that way.

Your last subquery is a little trickier to handle this way. I suggest you work with this answer and then maybe ask another question about that.